# Replace two placeholders in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file

I am trying to use placeholders to replace two words within a file. How can I make it so that my code in python can replace both of those values without making duplicate files of the same names.

```
PLACEHOLDER = "[name]"
SENDER = input("What is your name?: ")
PLACEHOLDER2 = "[sender_name]"


with open("names") as names_file:
    names = names_file.readlines()
    print(names)


with open("birthday_card") as birthday_card:
    card_contents = birthday_card.read()
    for name in names:
        stripped_names = name.strip()
        new_card = card_contents.replace(PLACEHOLDER, stripped_names)
        new_card = card_contents.replace(PLACEHOLDER2,  SENDER)
        with open (f"{stripped_names}.txt", mode="w") as completed_card:
            completed_card.write(new_card)
```

Comment: For community member convenience, please provide input and expected output. So that anyone can understand it easily and provide you best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `names` file format is the following:

```
  nic

sofi
nic   

 sofi
john
```

Names are separated by newline characters, with eventual leading and trailing whitespaces and random newlines, and also allowing duplicate names.

To remove duplicate names, you can use the set data structure instead of a list. A set is an unordered, unchangeable, and unindexed collection that can contain only unique values. The latter characteristic is what we're interested in since we don't want duplicate names.

I made a few changes to your code and added comments to explain the reason behind every choice:

```py
PLACEHOLDER = "[name]"
# Also strip the sender name
SENDER = input("What is your name?: ").strip()
PLACEHOLDER2 = "[sender_name]"


with open("names") as names_file:
    # Filter the lines from the file to remove
    # empty lines and then strip the names in-place
    # Create a set instead of a list to remove duplicates
    names = set(filter(lambda name: name != '', [name.strip() for name in names_file.readlines()]))

    # The code above is equivalent to:
    """
        names = []
        for name in names_file.readlines():
            name = name.strip()
            if name != '':
                names.append(name)
        names = set(names)
    """
    # However, the expanded for-loop alternative is less efficient

    print(names)


with open("birthday_card") as birthday_card:
    card_contents = birthday_card.read()
    
    for name in names:

        # No need to strip the name here, as we already did it

        # Replace the first placeholder with the name
        new_card = card_contents.replace(PLACEHOLDER, name)
        
        # Replace the second placeholder with the sender's name
        # Note that we use the `.replace` method on 
        # `new_card` here, and not `card_contents`
        new_card = new_card.replace(PLACEHOLDER2,  SENDER)

        # Alternatively, you can chain the `.replace` calls like this
        # new_card = card_contents.replace(PLACEHOLDER, name).replace(PLACEHOLDER2, SENDER)

        with open (f"{name}.txt", mode="w") as completed_card:
            completed_card.write(new_card)
```

And the resulting files:

```
$ ls -la | grep .txt

nic.txt
sofi.txt
john.txt
```

As you can see, although in the `names` file there were duplicate names, the generated files are unique.